# show message when no item found in suggesion list of autocomplete textview

Tags: android

I want a message when no item match suggestion list of AutocompleteTextView. if i use addOnTextChangeListener, then it show message all the time user type a char but i want it only when no match found. So please tell me how to do this, list is coming from web service. thanking you.

```
searchEdit = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searchEdit);
    searchEdit.setCursorVisible(false);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, menuItems);
    searchEdit.setAdapter(adapter);
    searchEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (!searchEdit.isPerformingCompletion()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Item Found", 2000).show();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You get all the Strings initially? or every time the text is changed?(in `onTextChanged`)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my answer is late, but I have solved the problem this way:

```
searchEdit.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length() > 2) {
            if (!searchEdit.isPopupShowing()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Edit your answer with explanation.

Comment: Thanks ZygD, excuse me for my bad english ;)

Comment: this is not the best answer, the popup can take a while to appear and you have both an error AND a popup displayed

Answer (score 2):

Just bumped into the same problem. Toasts are lame, it is much cooler to show the same drop down adapter as suggestions, but with only one item telling "no suggestions" or something like that. That's how google maps application work, for example.

There are two moments in this solution. First of all, if you have all items available on your phone already, you only need to change your adapter filter. In my case every user input results in Http request, which returns list of suggestions or empty list. So here how I do it

```
 List<AddressItem> cities = event.getCities();
    if(cities.isEmpty()) {
        AddressItem placeholder = AddressItem.placeholder(getContext());
        cities.add(placeholder);
    }
    AddressItemAdapter addressItemAdapter = new AddressItemAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.simple_text_view, cities);
    autoCompleteCity.setAdapter(addressItemAdapter);
    autoCompleteCity.showDropDown();
    progressCity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Here is a static method placeholder() for placeholder item. 
The second moment is that this item should not be clickable. So you need to check it's id in your adapter method...

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return items.get(position).getId == INVALID_ID;
}
```

To make it work, your adapter should put proper id in this method

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position).getId();
}
```

And you placeholder should have id field equal to INVALID_ID.
I hope my explanations will lead you to bettor UX than these Toasts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: you put toast into afterTextChanged() function

```
  searchEdit = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searchEdit);
searchEdit.setCursorVisible(false);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, menuItems);
searchEdit.setAdapter(adapter);
searchEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);

 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
  if (!searchEdit.isPerformingCompletion()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Item Found", 2000).show();
    return;
}
}
 @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {

 }
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}
```

Comment: Autocompletetextview has focus and if no item matches then i have to show message, but i completed it in other(exaustive search is performed in onTextChange() callback)

Answer (score 0):

autosearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                autosearch.getLayoutParams().width = JNConstants.WIDTH_35;
                rel_layer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {

                if(!autosearch.isPerformingCompletion()){
                    if( jnApp.getSearch_result().size()==0)
                            {
                        Log.v("mytag", "search_results_none");

                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.search_results_none), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        t.show();
                        return;

                    }
                    }

                autosearch.getLayoutParams().width = JNConstants.WIDTH_15;
            }
        }
    });
```